# error while generating apk in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am new to android development as well as in android studio. I was able to generate apk till now, but suddenly this error occurred, while generating apk it is showing,

> Error: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of 
>   com/intellij/openapi/util/io/FileUtil.toSystemDependentName must not be null"

Please help... I tried removing the gradle files and android studio to download it by itself, tried re-installing of android studio, but nothing helped.